# How do I properly annotate cooperative inherance in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Suppose I have something like this:

```py
from typing import Mapping, Any


class Hidden:

    def __init__(self, z: float, **kwargs: Any):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.z = z


class Base:

    def __init__(self, x: int, **kwargs: Any):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x


class Inherited(Base):

    def __init__(self, y: int, **kwargs: Any):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.y = y


class Final(Inherited, Hidden):
    pass
```

How should I annotate it?  I tried replacing `Any` with some uses of `TypedDict`, but it just wants the value type.  Is this the best I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update
Since `Inherited` needs both `x` and `y` to initialize, they should be explicitly defined as arguments. The kwargs is used for cooperative inheritance to allow for one class to call the other's init without explicitly worrying about what the type of arguments (here `z:float`) is. Hence `Any` is indeed the correct annotation in this case.

Similarly, in order to initialize `Final`, I would recommend defining `__init__` with all the required necessary arguments i.e., `def __init__(self, x:int, y:int, z:float, **kwargs:Any)`

Again here, Final can also be inherited from by other class and it doesn't care for the arguments of the derived class, but keep `**kwargs:Any` for cooperative inheritance compatibility

ps, sorry about going round and round about the same thing.

Old Answer
kwargs in python is a dict of key value pairs that are not among the explicitly defined arguments for the method. Hence the `**kwargs` would end up collecting any `foo=bar` argument where `foo` is not in the defined arguments.
The value `bar` can be just about anything which is why `Any` is used since `**` represents that the values will be wrapped up in a kwargs dict by nature.
You can annotate the type of value `bar` here though.
`**kwargs:int` would mean you can pass any undeclared key value pair so far as it is an int.

Comment: Also inherited doesn't know about hidden. So a union isn't good enough.

Comment: I agree with your description of the problem though

Comment: Since x, y, z are necessary to initialize Final, shouldn't they be explicitly defined?

Comment: The problem is you don't know about z, so you can't explicity define it in Inherited regardless of what you do in Final.

Comment: I think using Any is indeed the right way here in each class, since each class is only concerned about it's own x/y/z only and hence independent of the other. For Inherited, I would explicitly define `x:int, y:int` since that's the necessary condition for it to initialize. Personally I use kwargs for rarely used optional arguments not for necessary args

Comment: Though Inherited doesn't know about z, if Inherited can be initialized without z or even Hidden even existing, it shouldn't care about the type annotations for z. Hence `Any`

Comment: Makes sense, can you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: Updated the answer as requested.